# Iterate over two nested lists in parallel using purrr functions

Tags: r, purrr

I'm playing around with some of the `purrr` functions and discoverd (to my delight) `purrr::at_depth(.x, .depth, .f, ...)` which is short for `purrr::map(x, . %>% map(fun))`.

**Question:** *Is there a similar function or a proper "`purrr`-way" of doing the same thing when I have two nested lists that I want to iterate over in parallel*

As an example:

```
x <- list(list(10, 20), list(30, 40))
y <- list(list(1, 2), list(3, 4))

a <- list()
for(i in seq_along(x)) {
   a[[i]] <- map2(x[[i]], y[[i]], `+`) 
}
```

This works but its rather dirty and I'd like to avoid the for loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have list of lists and `+` is not vectorized for lists, you can use `map2` two times, the first `map2` loops through x, y simultaneously and the second `map2` add sub lists in an element wise fashion:

```
map2(x, y, map2, `+`)

#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1] 11

#[[1]][[2]]
#[1] 22


#[[2]]
#[[2]][[1]]
#[1] 33

#[[2]][[2]]
#[1] 44
```

Comment: Nice, thats what I was looking for. Thx!